# C++20 default equality / inequality

Tags: c++, c++20

C++20 gives us the spaceship operator and even allows us to `default` it, generating all comparisons with default semantics, which will remove a lot of boilerplate from our code bases, great!

But how about equality and inequality? Does C++20 also give us a way to `default` equality and inequality? <s>According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons), defaulting spaceship will only give us `<` `<=` `>`, and `>=`, but not `==` and `!=`. Given that I usually need equality/inequality way more often than greater/less, this seems to be quite unfortunate.</s> So, is there a way to also (or only) default generate `==` and `!=` in C++20?

Update: The page now contains a description for defaulting `operator==`. Seems that I accessed the page like two hours before the documentation for this was added. :D

Comment: I think the answer is [here](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/07/28/comparisons-cpp20/)

Comment: That page says: "This section is incomplete Reason: Defaulted equality comparisons".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does C++20 also give us a way to default equality and inequality?

Yes (but see the last paragraph). The syntax is same:

```
friend bool operator==(const T&, const T&) = default;
friend bool operator!=(const T&, const T&) = default; // not needed if == exists
```

The ordered inequality can be defaulted also:

```
friend bool operator<=(const T&, const T&) = default;
// ...
```

> defaulting spaceship will only give us `<` `<=` `>`, and `>=`, but not `==` and `!=`

This is inaccurate. Defaulting three way comparison gives us all comparisons So, the above are not needed in that case.

Comment: You don't need to second line.

Comment: @NathanOliver Regardless, it is allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. Doesn't it have to be a member `operator==` to be defaulted?

Comment: does this `==` use `<` or the members `==` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.eq#3

Comment: Interesting! This is not mentioned in cppreference.com. Or is it just in a place where I can't find it? At least the page about comparisons doesn't mention it.

Comment: @eerorika: And does it mean that this sentence at cppreference.com is inaccurate or rather incomplete: "In brief, a class that defines operator<=> automatically gets compiler-generated operators <, <=, >, and >=."

Comment: @gexicide Defaulting == seems to have been added to cppreference today, a well as *"Per the rules for any operator<=> overload, a defaulted <=> overload will also allow the type to be compared with <, <=, >, and >=. If operator<=> is defaulted and operator== is not defined at all, then operator== is also considered to be defaulted."*

Comment: @eerorika Oh my god, you are right. Does that mean I just browsed that page like 2 hours too early before it was added. That's funny.

Comment: @gexicide Who knows, maybe someone read this question and decided to update it.

Comment: @cigien: It has to be a member or friend—that is, declared in the class.  (You can defer defaulting it for the usual reasons.)

Comment: @DavisHerring Huh, interesting. That makes sense, I've just never seen it written that way. Thanks for clarifying :)